# Помогите с nodejs модуль request timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

```
 var options = {
    url:  'https://google.com',
    timeout: 1500
    }
    var url = 'https://google.com';
    request(options, function(err, res, body){
  if(err){console.log(err);}
  else{ 
    console.log(body)
}}
```

У меня недавно появилась проблема, сайт некоторые элементы стал загружать после того как уже загрузилась страница. Например, я захожу на яндекс и элемент новости дозагрузится через секунд 10. Поэтому если спарсить страницу, у меня не будет элемента погоды. Пробовал таймаут, явно не то) помогите)

Comment: Вам надо в консоли браузера поизучать, откуда он грузит новости (скорее всего это ajax-запрос), и загружать то что вам нужно напрямую оттуда

Comment: По моему опыту, данные основных виджетов (вроде погоды и новостей) приходят в первом же запросе [скрин](http://joxi.net/V2Vne8LU07lyE2.jpg)

Comment: спасибо Darth, да вы правы , загружается отдельно другая страница, нашел ее и теперь все гуд)

Answer (score 0):

У меня всё работает. Может быть, я просто не те данные проверяю.

Вот с этим же кодом:

```js
var request = require('request');

var test = {
  run: function() {
    var options = {
      url:  'https://www.yandex.ru',
      timeout: 1500
    }
    request(options, function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else { 
        console.log(body)
      }
    });
  }
};
```

У меня получается найти в ответе (то, что в *body*) и новости, и погоду. Проверял так: одновременно загружал в браузере и скриптом, выделял в браузере текст (заголовок новости или прогноз погоды), искал в строке ответа - всё находится.